Is there a way to see who ran a manual stage in an ADO YAML pipeline?
Me and my team are trying to utilize the somewhat recently added manual stages in our YAML piplines. We would like to use them for our production deployments that we don't want automated.
Our issue is that we need to know who manually started the production stage for auditing purposes, but cannot seem to find any way to do this either through the UI, pipeline variables, or APIs (looking at timeline record, builds, pipeline runs).
Can this information be found anywhere and if so, how do I find it?
